# Question: A name for Food/drink lover

Tags: nouns, adverbs

Someone who likes to taste everything, like food and drink. But I don't mean a glutton

Comment: Babies like to taste everything. So perhaps consider [**neotenic**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neotenic). Or just **oral** [-fixated].

Answer (score 0):

Gourmet, possibly. Not to be confused with 'gourmand' which means 'glutton'.

> gourmet noun [ C ] UK ​  /ˈɡɔː.meɪ/ US ​  /ˈɡʊr.meɪ/ ​ a person who
>   knows a lot about food and cooking, and who enjoys eating high-quality
>   food

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gourmet

Answer (score 0):

bon vivant    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bon+vivant)

> A person with refined taste, especially one who enjoys superb food and
>   drink.

Answer (score 0):

The word "foodie" would be appropriate.